# How can you `co_await` in a C++/WinRT lambda?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-async

Can you `co_await` in a C++/WinRT TimerElapsedHandler (or any other lambda in C++/WinRT)?

When I try to compile code like this:

```cpp
auto pointerExitedTimerHandler = winrt::TimerElapsedHandler([](const winrt::ThreadPoolTimer&)
{
    co_await 5s;

    // Other stuff...
});
```

I get an error:

```
error C7588: A definition of a class template std::experimental::task must be provided for the return type of this coroutine to be deduced
```

How can I write an async handler?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to provide an async return type. For example, `-> winrt::fire_and_forget`:

```cpp
auto pointerExitedTimerHandler = winrt::TimerElapsedHandler([](const winrt::ThreadPoolTimer&) -> winrt::fire_and_forget
{
    co_await 5s;

    // Other stuff...
});
```

[Fire and forget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#fire-and-forget) is a simple WinRT wrapper for async functions that ignores the result—if you need to await the result, you'll need to use a different return type.

Comment: I can't mark it as accepted for a few hours, since it's my own answer!